# Test uses internal ContextConfiguration of other test

Tags: java, spring, testing, configuration, spring-data-jpa

I created a new test in my Project. For this one I used `@ContextConfiguration` with an internal Configuration class in the same class as the Test. But now my other tests are failing because they are using the configuration of the new test.
How is this possible, I thought it is not possible to use a configuration inside of a test class from outside.

When I remove the internal configuration from the new test every other test works fine again.

```
@DataJpaTest
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = EventServiceTest.Config.class)
class EventServiceTest {
    @Configuration
    @Import({WorkingTimeConfig.class,
             PartnerConfig.class,
             ProjectConfig.class,
             UserConfig.class,
             AccountGroupConfig.class,
             LanguageConfig.class,
             CountryConfig.class,
             EventConfig.class,
             LanguageConfig.class})
    static class Config {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @MockBean(reset = MockReset.BEFORE)
        private UserAttendanceBoard userAttendanceBoard;

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        }

        @Bean
        public ImpersonateProperties impersonateProperties() {
            return new ImpersonateProperties();
        }
    }
...
}
```

Now this Test is not working:

```
@Import(MailSenderAutoConfiguration.class)
@DataJpaTest
@Transactional
public class ServiceTimeEntryServiceTest {

    private ServiceTimeService serviceTimeService;
    private ServiceTimeEntryRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public ServiceTimeEntryServiceTest(ServiceTimeService serviceTimeService, ServiceTimeEntryRepository repository) {
        this.serviceTimeService = serviceTimeService;
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Test
    void getAllByAccountId() {...}
```

This error is thrown if I try to start my old tests:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'passwordEncoder' defined in class path resource [de/hlservices/timetracking/api/business/event/EventServiceTest$Config.class]: Cannot register bean definition

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Maciej Kowalski pointed out, this issue is probably related to a `@ComponentScan` annotation.

If you're using it, consider adding an `excludeFilter` to ensure you only get what you really want. You might want to exclude other configuration classes to be found by your `@ComponentScan` annotation:

```
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION,
                value = Configuration.class)
})
```

Btw: I really recommend using IntelliJ IDEA as IDE because of the awesome spring support.
You can lookup what beans/components are found by your scan just by clicking on the green icon left of your code (line:9) :

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Spring Support]

This makes debugging scanning issues way easier.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much :)
I've now added the filter to all my Configs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my project and it was due to the fact that the `@ComponentScan` was picking up also that class due to the `@Configuration` annotation.

Everything worked fine when I removed that annotation and thus making the component scan to omit it. So you can have just like that:

```
@Import({WorkingTimeConfig.class,
             PartnerConfig.class,
             ProjectConfig.class,
             UserConfig.class,
             AccountGroupConfig.class,
             LanguageConfig.class,
             CountryConfig.class,
             EventConfig.class,
             LanguageConfig.class})
    static class Config {
```

Removing `@Configuration` annotation did not prevent `@ContextConfiguration(classes = EventServiceTest.Config.class)` config to pick it up anyway.

Comment: Removing `@Configuration`. removes also the special handling of the class as configuration class. Adding it to `@Import` doesn't make it a configuration class in the sense of `@Configuration`. but rather a configuration-lite mode (a regular component with `@Bean` methods). These are treated differently and might lead to surprising effects!.

Comment: Wow didnt know that. Thanks for pointing it out. Ineed I did not have any additional annotaions on my inner test configuration classes. Maybe thats why I did not see any problems

Comment: Tanks for your answer. You are right, when I remove the @Configuration all other tests are working again. But now the new test is not working because he is not using the internal config class. 
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve @EnableAutoConfiguration base packages`